# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,3,3) into shape (441,3,3)

Tags: python, image, crop, opencv

I am tyring to crop an image using cv2 module but get the error from the title.

The problematic line is: `images_cropped[index, :, :, :] = _img`

So I am broadcasting 3 dimensions pic into 3 dimensions. Sounds OK. Broadcasting smaller size into a bigger one, sounds OK too.
I've googled a lot, never found anyone having same problem, they either have different amount of dimensions in each shape or trying to put bigger shape into a smaller one.

```
    for r, dirs, files in os.walk(foldername):

        for file in files:
            _img = cv2.imread(os.sep.join([r, file]))
            if _img is not None:
                # estimate the watermark part
                image_paths.append(os.sep.join([r, file]))
                _img = _img[_s[0]:(_s[0]+_e[0]), _s[1]:(_s[1]+_e[1]), :]
                # add to list images
                images_cropped[index, :, :, :] = _img
                index+=1
            else:
                print("%s not found."%(file))

    return (images_cropped, image_paths)
```

I can't understand why it can't fill (441,3,3) with (0,3,3), any ideas?

Comment: what are the shapes of everything? `_img`, `_images_cropped`

Comment: (0, 3, 3) for `_img` and `_images_cropped` is not generated yet because of an error

Comment: I mean its empty

Comment: [[[[0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0.]]

  [[0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0.]]

  [[0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0.]]

Comment: _images_cropped does not have an empty shape, if it's all zeros, what is the shape of `images_cropped[index, :, :, :]`? It is most likely `(441, 3, 3)`, in which case `(0,3,3)` will not work.

Comment: `(0,3,3)` itself seems to be an indexing error

Comment: `print images_cropped[index, :, :, :]` won't work throws `IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Comment: check your spaces mate, and what version of `python` are you using?

Comment: `[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 ...

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]]`

Comment: `Python 2.7.10`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218475/discussion-between-m-z-and-narra-kk).